# Plotting candlestick and volume candels in Bokeh

Tags: python, pandas-bokeh

I have plotted the candlestick using bokeh. Now i want to plot the volume candles in the same chart?
How do I achieve that. I am reading the data from csv which has open,high,low,close and volume.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extension of the example of the offical documentation for a [candlestick](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/candlestick.html).

If you don't have the data yet, run this snippet first.

```
import bokeh
bokeh.sampledata.download()
```

If the data is available, you can create the candlestick like before.
With the gridplot function you join the first figure with seconde one.

```
from math import pi

import pandas as pd

from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.layouts import gridplot
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import MSFT

output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame(MSFT)[:50]
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])

inc = df.close > df.open
dec = df.open > df.close
w = 12*60*60*1000 # half day in ms

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"

p1 = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools=TOOLS, plot_width=700, plot_height=300, title = "MSFT Candlestick with Volume")
p1.xaxis.visible = False
p1.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
p1.grid.grid_line_alpha=0.3

p1.segment(df.date, df.high, df.date, df.low, color="black")
p1.vbar(df.date[inc], w, df.open[inc], df.close[inc], fill_color="#D5E1DD", line_color="black")
p1.vbar(df.date[dec], w, df.open[dec], df.close[dec], fill_color="#F2583E", line_color="black")

p2 = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", tools="", toolbar_location=None, plot_width=700, plot_height=200, x_range=p1.x_range)
p2.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
p2.grid.grid_line_alpha=0.3
p2.vbar(df.date, w, df.volume, [0]*df.shape[0])

show(gridplot([[p1],[p2]]))
```

To change the look a bit the x-axis of figure 1 is invisible using `p1.xaxis.visible = False` and there is no title defined for figure 2.
To link the two figures together, the x_range of figure 1 is passed to figure two unsing `x_range=p1.x_range`.

The output is this:
[image: candlestick with volume]

Comment: How would you overlay the volume on top of the price chart, similar to the way TradingView does it?

Comment: Does this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66232643/plotting-candlesticks-and-volume-bars-in-bokeh-on-the-same-figure/66247198#66247198) answer your question?