# Plotting candlesticks and volume bars in Bokeh on the same figure

Tags: python, bokeh

Basically, I'd like to do the same thing as [shown in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64876637/plotting-candlestick-and-volume-candels-in-bokeh), but with two additional modifications:

- Combine the candlestick and volume into one figure
- Have two y axes, so that they are scrolled / zoomed independently (e.g. when a candlestick axis is wheel-zoomed, only candlesticks should change in size, not volume bars - and vice-versa for the volume bars)

Is that something that can be done with Bokeh?

Comment: Check out the [twin axis example](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/examples/basic/axes/twin_axes.html) the see different options for scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to merge the two figures into one. And since **bokeh 3.2.0** it is possible to scroll the axis independently.
A legend is added to hide the data which is not in your focus as well.

If you don't have the data yet, run this snippet first.

```
import bokeh
bokeh.sampledata.download()
```

This is the code to create the figure.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.sampledata.stocks import MSFT
from bokeh.models import LinearAxis, Range1d, Segment, Legend
output_notebook()

df = pd.DataFrame(MSFT)[:50]
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])
inc = df.close > df.open
dec = df.open > df.close
w = 12*60*60*1000 # half day in ms

TOOLS = "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save"
p = figure(
    x_axis_type="datetime",
    tools=TOOLS,
    width=700,
    height=300,
    title = "MSFT Candlestick with Volume"
)
p.add_layout(Legend(click_policy="hide", orientation='horizontal', spacing=20), 'below')
# left y axis
low, high  = df[['open', 'close']].min().min(), df[['open', 'close']].max().max()
diff = high-low
p.y_range = Range1d(low-0.1*diff, high+0.1*diff)
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Price'
p.segment(df.date, df.high, df.date, df.low, color="black", legend_label='Candlestick')
p.vbar(df.date[inc], w, df.open[inc], df.close[inc], 
       fill_color="#D5E1DD", line_color="black", legend_label='Candlestick')
p.vbar(df.date[dec], w, df.open[dec], df.close[dec], 
       fill_color="#F2583E", line_color="black", legend_label='Candlestick')
# right y axis
p.extra_y_ranges.update({'two':  Range1d(0, 1.1*df.volume.max())})
p.add_layout(LinearAxis(y_range_name='two', axis_label='Volume' ), 'right')
p.vbar(df.date, w, df.volume, [0]*df.shape[0], alpha=0.5, level='underlay', 
       legend_label='Volume', y_range_name='two')
wheel_zoom = p.toolbar.tools[1]
wheel_zoom.zoom_together='none' # can be 'none', 'cross', 'all'
p.toolbar.active_scroll = wheel_zoom
show(p)
```

The created figure looks like this.
[image: stock with two y axis]

Comment: Do you know if there's a way in Bokeh to allow a user to draw lines with their mouse on the graph from inside the browser?

Comment: There is the [FreehandDrawTool](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#freehanddrawtool) which allows to draw something with the mouse.